# Issue installing python windows extension

Tags: python-2.7

I installed Python 2.7.6 Windows Installer (Windows binary) and then, I was trying to install the extension `pywin32-218.win-amd64-py2.7.exe`. But everytime I run this extension, I get the issue of `"pywin32-218.win-amd64-py2.7.exe has stopped working"`.

Comment: Where do it stop? In the installer, or in the python editor?

Comment: In installer, after it shows the prompt where it shows the installation directory for this extension, when I click `Next`, it stops working.

Comment: @ChristianSauer Sorry, it was this extension that stopped working, not windows. I have updated the question!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Have you downloaded the correct pywin version (32 bit or 64bit python?).

Comment: Also, maybe the download is curropted, I had the issue last week when downloading scipy - so download it again

Answer (score 1):

You should `run` the `exe` file as `"Administrator"`. 
Even if you are in the administrator account, you have to explicitly run it with administrator permission by right clicking on the `exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it as administrator, anything that modifies folders it is not in or in its folder require root access which is right click -> run as admin in Windows or sudo in mac and linux.